# How to implement recalculate function in VBA ?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sets of text boxes A,B and C,D. I have to manually enter the values in A and B while the code in the backend calculates C = A/(A + B) and D = B/(A + B).

If I change the values in A and B, the values in C and D get updated.

Is there any way the reverse could happen.

My apologies if this is not a recalculate function related question.

Thanks again!

Comment: If C is changed then should A or B be updated?  Both?

Comment: Is this just a textbox or is it in a userform?

Comment: Tim - No if C changes only A must change and also D must change

Comment: Wyatt - This is a userform

Comment: "if C changes only A must change and also D must change" I'm sorry, that's not anywhere near anything reasonably clear. "only A must change" and "and also D must change" sound like mutually exclusive possibilities to me. Please [edit] your question to clatify, as it stands it's not clear what the problem is, what you've tried, and where you're stuck.

Comment: Mat's Mug - Since C and D are percentages and they add upto 100%, I would like D to change when C is changed manually and since C is associated to A, I also want A to change when C is changed. Let me know if this is clear enough

Comment: If D is changed should B (and C) be updated?

Comment: Hint - try transforming `C = A/(A + B)` to move A to the left of the equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

I would create a single method o handle the logic.  You'll have to set a flag to prevent re-triggering your calculations.

```
Public StopCalculations As Boolean

Private Sub a_Change()
    If Not StopCalculations Then UpdateValues a
End Sub

Private Sub b_Change()
    If Not StopCalculations Then UpdateValues b
End Sub

Private Sub c_Change()
    If Not StopCalculations Then UpdateValues c
End Sub

Private Sub d_Change()
    If Not StopCalculations Then UpdateValues d
End Sub

Sub UpdateValues(txt As MSForms.TextBox)
    StopCalculations = True

    Select Case txt
        Case a
           b.value = a.value
        Case b
            b.value = c.value
        Case c

        Case d
    End Select

    StopCalculations = False
End Sub
```

You can store and retrieve hidden values in the workbooks names collection like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    a.value = getNameValue(a.Name)
    b.value = getNameValue(b.Name)
    c.value = getNameValue(c.Name)
    d.value = getNameValue(d.Name)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add a.Name, a.Text, False
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add b.Name, b.Text, False
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add c.Name, c.Text, False
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add d.Name, d.Text, False
End Sub

Function getNameValue(value As String)
    Dim s As String
    On Error Resume Next
    s = ThisWorkbook.Names(value).value
    getNameValue = Right(s, Len(s) - 1)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```